# Is it possible to invoke a common method in a list without iterating?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using C# and I don't know if it's possible invoke a method for all the object in a list in the same moment, without loop like for or foreach.

Ex.

```
class Person
{
    public void doSomething()
    {
    //
    }
}

List<Person> _personlist = new List<Person>();

_personlist(SelectAll.doSomething()); //something like this
//invoke the same method at the same time for all the object in the list
```

I think that Linq allow this, but at the moment I don't find anything.

Comment: Do you want to call a function for all the objects in a list at the exact same time? Ex. CheckPrice(all objects in listOfProducts)

Comment: @MasterXD exactly, without loop

Comment: It is impossible to do it all at once. You have to make some kind of iteration. If you just loop through all objects before continuing to the upcomming logic, it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: and using reflection?
Ex. Method[].Invoke()

Comment: I have little to no experience using reflection, but I dont see how it should be possible using reflection either. The thing is, it is not neccecary to do it all at once. You could show some code to show why you need it all to happen at once though.

Comment: Couldnt you do it with a clever threading implementation?

Comment: I have to save time... Only this

Comment: Don't you want to show us some code? in order to understand what exactly you are trying to do!!!

Comment: @Muckeypuck can you explain?

Comment: well if you launched 5 threads and had them all listening to an event on another object, couldnt you have each thread fire the method when the event fires?

Comment: though i tend to agree with everyone else that this requirement doesnt appear to pass the smell test and you should prolly explain what youre trying to do. my answer is academic, not necessarily practical

Comment: you could unroll the list into individual items.  but if you can't go multithreaded there is no way to do work on multiple items at the same time.

Comment: if you want to write a query that can operate in parallel check out plinq. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MatthewWhited **YES!!** it's exactly this! If you post your answer i accept it and we can help somepeople that have the same problem...

Comment: As a note PLINQ is the opposite of what you asked for with "without loop like for or foreach and without multithread".

Comment: i think it create a thread for all object in the list right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a query that can operate in parallel check out [plinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997425(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var _personlist = new List<Person>();
_personlist.AsParallel().ForAll(i=>i.DoSomething());
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to iterate the List, either way.

LINQ is not really useful for producing side effects, it is for querying collections. You can call your method with LINQ, but it will do the iteration *(internally)*.

So it is better that you use an explicit loop construct to convey the code intention clearly.

With LINQ if your object has a instant method than you can do:

```
var something = yourList.Select(r=> r.MethodToCall()).ToList();
```

But don't do the above...

Answer (score -1):

LINQ does offer a ForEach extension method that can give you a one liner option. It's technically still a loop though....

This is an example I've used before...

```
List<StreamWriter> Writers;
...
Writers.ForEach(x => x.Write(...));
```

Comment: Yes. You have to loop through the list. You can't do multiple things all at once.

Answer (score -1):

On the List object you can call the extension method ForEach.

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
numbers.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: The OP said that you can't iterate the list.  You're iterating the list.